# image zooming is displaying in right side of the page

Tags: magento-1.9, product, image, product-images, product-view

In Product view page, image is serving from this path : [link](http://test.collagekingapp.com/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/350x350/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/b/a/baby-ball-large.jpg)

```
/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/350x350/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/b/a/ball.jpg
```

it's using 350x350 size

but i wanted to serve from this path : [link2](http://test.collagekingapp.com/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/850x850/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/b/a/baby-ball-large.jpg)

`media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/850x850/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/b/a/ball.jpg`

I need **850x850** size.

we are using : `<?php echo $dexxtz->getImageFeatured($this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'image')); ?>`

**Edit**

when i change size values in backend as below, images are serving from path i required. but in product view page, when we hover on product image, its zooming on right side of the page as [link3](http://test.collagekingapp.com/pampers-active-baby-large-size-diapers-78-count-combo.html) but before it was working fine as [link4](http://totaltoys.com/pampers-active-baby-large-size-diapers-78-count-combo.html)

[image]

Comment: Do you want to change product image size ?

Comment: @Arunendra i want to keep the same size, i want to images should serve from 850 * 850 path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just call the `resize()` method after the helper init:

```
<?php echo $dexxtz->getImageFeatured($this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'image')->resize(850)); ?>
```

Comment: sorry, it didt worked for me.